# How does one evaluate the amount of spilled water of an open revolving cylindrical tank?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

For quite a while I've been working on the following problem:

> An open cylindrical tank $2R$ meters in diameter and $H$ meters tall contains $h$ meters of water. The tank is revolved around its own vertical axis in such a way that the free surface's paraboloid touches the tanks base. How much water will be spilled?

I came up with some initial conditions, but I still cannot think of a way to find the minimum omega for which the paraboloid will touch the bed. I'm new to fluid mechanics - any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the paraboloidal surface intersect the wall of the cylinder at any speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that any information about fluid dynamics is needed.  This seems to be purely a mathematics problem.

You have enough information to calculate the volume of water originally in the cylinder.

If you assume that after spin-up the resultant water surface touches both the centre of the cylinder bottom **and the circular rim at the top of the cylinder** then again you have enough information to calculate the volume of this assumed final shape.

Deal with this second volume being less than, equal to, or greater than the original volume...